# Trying to go through a list of strings and add count to then end of strings

Tags: string, scheme, racket

I am trying to use the racket simple-qr library and take in a list of strings which would be websites and create qrs  for each item.

this is what I have:

```
#lang racket
(require simple-qr)

;;auto makes a qr for the main source of simple-qr
(qr-code "https://github.com/simmone" "gitSource.png")

;;asking the user to imput a string so that
;;they can create their own qr code
;;they can also name it themselves
(define (makeQRForME mystring namestring)
  (qr-code mystring (string-append namestring ".png")))

(define count 0)

(define (addqrlist lst)
  (if (null? lst) lst
    (makeQRForME (car lst) (string-append "stringQR"(number->string(+ 1 count)))))
    (addqrlist (rest lst)))
```

I am reletively new to racket and am having trouble writing this iterate function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would write the function in Racket:

```
(define (make-qr-codes texts)
  (for ((text (in-list texts))
        (count (in-naturals)))
    (qr-code text (format "stringQR~a.png" count))))
```

But, if you're trying to see how to fix your version, here's how I would do it:

```
(define (addqrlist lst)
  (let loop ((rest lst)
             (count 0))
    (unless (null? rest)
      (makeQRForMe (car rest) (format "stringQR~a" count))
      (loop (cdr rest) (add1 count)))))
```

(Your version mixes the use of `car` and `rest`, instead of `car` and `cdr` or `first` and `rest`. I changed it to use `car` and `cdr` consistently. Also, it's more readable to use `format` instead of `string-append` plus `number->string`.)